# Indoor ant control: Caulk up baseboard and counter/wall junction?

Tags: insect, ants

**Background**

I rent a 1-bedroom apartment on the 9th floor of a highrise.  I've
been trying to solve an ant problem over the past two months,
including three bouts of commercial bait that is suppose to eradicate
the colony.  The problem only abates for a few days.  The landlord has
already brought in a pest control expert a week ago, who merely dabbed
some gel at two spots (kitchen and bathroom).  The problem remains
unchanged, despite hieghtened vigilance in cleaning (I'm was already a
clean freak beforehand).  I may have to ask for fumigation.  I believe
that the landlord would be justified in inspecting neighbouring
apartments, but that's not within my control.

From what I've researched online, an ant problem might be an ongoing
management problem.

**The question**

As a means of mitigating the problem, prior to actually getting it
under control, would it be advisable to:

**(1)** Caulk up the junction between the baseboards and the wall,
   between the  shoe moulding and the baseboard, and between the shoe
   moulding and the floor?

**(2)** Caulk up or re-caulk the junction between the kitchen
   counter and the wall, and between the washroom vanity and the wall?

My thinking is that restricting their mobility makes their life and
survival more difficult, but I am also concerned that it may reduce
the effectivenes of other measures.  For example, it may interfere
with their bringing bait back to the colony, or make satellite
colonies more likely.  Or it may impede fumigation, if that happens.

Comment: Caulking is unlikely to be a final solution, ants can squeeze through the tiniest of openings, and there a likely to be hidden openings that you can't access. Different species of ants require different treatments, the "expert" should know, but sometimes they don't. Their size and what they are attracted to can help determine the species.

Comment: OK, thanks.  They are 1.5-2mm long, gray/tan colour.  I wasn't thinking about caulking to vacuum seal the place, but just to impeded their mobility.  Wondering if that strategy might backfire in the manner that I described.

Comment: Assuming you find the right type, bait is you best bet.

Comment: I posted a species identification question at [this Stack Exchange page](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/87747/species-identification-1-2mm-1-16-1-8-brownish-ant-in-highrise-apartment).  Thanks.

Comment: use boric acid on them. it might take a few months (literally) to kill all the (sub) colonies of all your neighbors, but it _will_ work. leave the bait around later so that any fresh ones get hit right away.

Comment: Since the beginning of August, I've used 3 bouts of Ortho Ant Bgon Max. According to [this blog page](http://vancouversun.com/news/staff-blogs/how-to-get-rid-of-ants-when-they-wont-eat-the-bait-traps), it is largely borax and sugar water. It remains largely untouched, and I don't seen them gather there. The exterminator also applied more powerful stuff about 1.5 weeks ago. It doesn't seemed to have changed. The best description of the entire episode is described [here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/87747/species-identification-2-5mm-3-32-or-1-5-8-brownish-ant-in-highrise-apartme).

Comment: The punch line is that I'm wondering if they're coming from neighbouring units. Due to the slow accumulation of small wood chips over the years, however, they may have been visiting for years. The current inundation might be a sign that they decided to colonize my apartment this summer.

Answer (score 1):

**bifenthrin**

you'll need a <=1 gal sprayer and mix rate up to ~1 ounce per gallon.  spray the entire place, let it dry.

another one is permethrin, in Martin's Cyonara.

both can be gotten at tractor supply, or amazon, sometimes at depot/lowes.

Comment: Thanks, Ron, but I have to work with my landlord company and its exterminator.  I found out that the infestation affects my neighbour below as well.  So far, the exterminator is going with the slow route of bait to exterminate the colony/colonies.  They might choose fumigation later.  This was more a question of whether caulking would actually improve the management of the ants while the bait works, which apparently can take months, or whether the caulking will backfire in the manner that I describe.d

Comment: a professional [honest] exterminator would simply spray bifen.  For < $20 u can spray it yourself it would be easier and cheaper than caulking.  a $10 8-oz bottle of bifen will last u years for just spraying your place.  let me guess terminix? baits = recurring visit = moneymaker.  spray bifen or cyonara around entire perimeter of your apt, ants cross it they die,  effective for 1-3 months, quite simple. once dry bifen & cyonara is safe including in food areas [kitchen cabinets but don't directly spray your dishes]

Comment: Hi, Ron, I marked "up" your answer, but didn't mark it as *the* answer because it answers a slightly different question.  Thanks.